# Who plays Agent Sam Chaney in this X Files episode?

Tags: the-x-files

The episode is called [Aubrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubrey_(The_X-Files)), and you only see Agent Sam Chaney for two very brief scenes. Once as a picture on a report Scully holds near the camera, and once in a flashback B.J. Morrow has. He looks like actor Jeffrey Combs to me, but its not listed in his filmography, and the actor for Sam Chaney was uncredited in the show.

[image]

Can someone confirm my suspicions, or else tell me otherwise? Thanks.

Comment: I spent entirely too much time on google image search looking for a match for this picture. I agree it looks like Jeffrey Combs, but I couldn't find a matching head shot for it.

Comment: Jeffrey Combs in CASTLE FREAK (it was also filmed in 1995): https://admitonefilmaddict.files.wordpress.com/2019/12/castle-freak-4.jpg, so this picture could be added to the post above.

Comment: Combs is on Twitter, @jeffreycombs.  Someone could ask him directly if it that was him.

Comment: Maybe that secret is a part of the plot ))

Comment: I don't have Twitter, but maybe one of you brave souls would be willing to @ him?

Comment: This kinda looks like [Peter Flemming](https://www.tvmaze.com/episodes/40455/the-x-files-2x12-aubrey) too .